# unregister_netdevice: waiting for bond0.100 to become free. Usage count = -1

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, network-bonding

I've created a bond-interface with systemd-networkd, with a wildcard for all eth*- and en*-Interfaces. The purpose is to attach and detach USB-network-devices to the bond automatically. On top of the bond0 interface is vlan-device with the ID 100.

I did the following:

- Attach an USB-C -> Ethernet Device (RTL8153 Chip)
- `ip link set bond0 up`
- `ip link add link bond0 name bond0.100 type vlan id 100`
- `ip link set bond0.100 up`
- Remove the network interface
- `ip link delete bond0.100`

The last command hangs and I'm not able to kill it. dmesg shows the following:

```
unregister_netdevice: waiting for bond0.100 to become free. Usage count = -1
unregister_netdevice: waiting for bond0.100 to become free. Usage count = -1
unregister_netdevice: waiting for bond0.100 to become free. Usage count = -1
unregister_netdevice: waiting for bond0.100 to become free. Usage count = -1
```

The systemd-networkd config looks like this:

10-bond0.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond
Description=Bonding ethernet devices

[Bond]
Mode=active-backup
PrimaryReselectPolicy=always
MIIMonitorSec=1s
```

20-ethernet.network

```
[Match]
Name=en* eth*

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

Note: I'm not using NetworkManager. All ip related stuff is managed manually. systemd-networkd is just creating the interfaces.

Is there a way to fix this error message and let the `ip link delete` command execute? Even an error message would be fine, as long as the command finishes.